# Using Google Tag Manager to track conversions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have managed to set up Google Tag Manager to fire off events to Google Analytics when links are clicked on different pages of my websites. I know it works as when I click the links, an alert shows up in Real Time --> Events section of Google Analytics.

I was wondering how to implement the following: For each page on my site I would like to see in Google Analytics the conversion which I define to be: Number of Relevant Links clicked on Page / Number of visits to Page. The numerator in this instance being whatever came from Google Tag Manager.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are tacking about metric, not conversion. For conversion tracking you have to define exact value.

To track such metric you can use calculated metric with a formula X/Pageviews, where X is  can be number of events (link clicks in your case).